# codeigniter session expiration

Tags: codeigniter, session, lifetime

I got a codeigniter session issue that I hasn't been able to solve. My sessions always expires even if my expiration time is set to "infinity". I've tried to set the expiration time to 0 and also a high number such as 604800 (one week).

At the moment my variables looks like this:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 604800;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

I've tried a lot of different combinations and a couple of different libraries but I can´t seem to find a solution for the problem. Do I have to change `gc_maxlifetime` in my php.ini file to make it work?

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735456/codeigniter-destroying-my-session-without/12741200) can help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using Firefox, and it´s the same in every browser. I appreciate you answer.

Comment: if you are using AJAX that can cause issues when the session ID gets regenerated. [stackoverflow-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381786/problem-with-session-in-codeigniter). I have also had several other issues with the CI sessions, but have never been able to track down the cause.

Comment: The problem is now solved by downloading the latest session library from codeigniter and thanks to some configurations.

Answer (score 0):

**Please change both the settings from TRUE to FALSE in your `config.php` files**

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
```