# Codeigniter : save data to session and display it with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I ran into issue with `sessions` and `ajax`. I have this peace of code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
    if(in_array($result[$i], $m_lines_arr)) {
        echo "<p class='br' style='color:   #ffffff'>Match on comb. $i</p>";
        $win = 10;
        $this->session->set_userdata( array('win' => $win));
    }
    else {
        echo "<p class='br'>No match on comb. $i</p>";
    }
}
```

So, if something is in array, give `$win` value `10` and save it do session, otherwise just do simple echo. 
In my function `win` I try to `echo` this `session`. Here is the sample of function `win`:

```
function win() {
    $win = $this->input->post('win');
    echo $this->session->userdata('win');
}
```

`Function win` comes after the `for loop`, just for you to know.

And here is the Ajax request:

```
var win = $('#win span').html();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/slots/index.php/game/win',
    data: { win: win },
    success:function(response) {
        $('#win span').html(response);
    }
});
```

The problem is, I can't display data stored in session in real time, I must refresh page to get the result. Any clue?

Comment: when does for loop gets executed? Is it script that ajax calls?

Comment: every time I press one button, but that loop doesn't matter. I have data stored in session, but ajax retrieve it after refresh. Ajax is in document.ready function

Comment: 2D array..don't btoher yourself with those data, I'm just trying to get data from session with ajax and present them in real time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381786/problem-with-session-in-codeigniter

Comment: @SheikhHeera Didn't understand his issue well..

Comment: `var win = $('#win span').html();`: is this piece of code fetching value inside span tag correctly???

Comment: win must me quoted like this :-  data: { 'win' : win }

Comment: @elavarasanlee yes, why? It is just taking the number inside span.
@ Sudz can you explain to me why please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function win() {
    echo $win = $this->input->post('win');
    // $this->session->userdata('win'); i don't think you need this if it's real time
}
```

but i prefer usually:

```
function win() {
    $win = $this->input->post('win');
    echo json_encode( array('win'=>$win));
}
```

then in ajax:

```
$.ajax({
 //...
dataType:'json',
 success:function(json){
 alert(json.win);
}
});
```

**NB, VERY VERY IMPORTANT, the session must be setted BEFORE any output, so here you are setting session after the output:**

```
 echo "<p class='br' style='color:   #ffffff'>Match on comb. $i</p>";
        $win = 10;
        $this->session->set_userdata( array('win' => $win));
```

do this:

```
$win = 10;
 $this->session->set_userdata( array('win' => $win)); //for better performance you must call this out from the loop
echo ."<p class='br' style='color:   #ffffff'>Match on comb. $i</p>";


    then in ajax:

$.ajax({
 //
success:function(response){
 alert(response);
}
});
```

Comment: @mihajloWR sure , let me now ;)

Comment: ok, so I need to make it in reverse order? And I forgot to mention, in my if(in_array...) I must make output in real time to my html code <div id="win">
    Win : <span>0</span>
   </div>

Comment: I removed that 'for' loop, to make it more simple. I know how it will work, but I don't know how to array form one function to another one, do you know maybe?

Let's say we have an array() with some data in it in function 'one', I dont't know how to pass that array to, let's say, function 'two'?

Comment: @mihajloWR well, **function a(){  b($array); }  function b($array){ //do somenthing with $array }**